# Kohana default template with header and footer blocks integrated

Tags: php, kohana

Goodevening guys,

A while ago, some of you helped me with some coding, when i couldn't find my error and such. Now i'm busy with a new project, and i want to make use of blocks inside my default template..

I got 2 blocks (header and footer). I got a default template where there is a line

```
echo View::factory('blocks/header_ss')->render();
```

The template itself contains the other code that's neccesary, in the header_ss file there is only the navigation menu. Now i want to talk to this block, from within the :

```
Controller_MyTemplate extends Controller_Template.
```

Now i want to talk to the header block template file from within the template controller file, but if i use a code like:

```
$this->template->menutitle = 'Blablabla';
```

Then i cannot use $menutitle in my header_ss template... it's logic because template refers to the main_ss template file..

```
$this->template->block->header['tag'] = 'Content';
```

It doesnt look logical to me but... well, i cant find it on google..

Thanks for all ur help in advance, if i've missed something, i'll add it on request.

Answer (score 0):

Well for one, you can keep the code in the template and do your logic there

```
$view = View::factory('blocks/header_ss');
$view->set('tag', 'Content');
echo $view->render();
```

However, this becomes quite messy after a while and having too much PHP in a template defeats the purpose of having templates in the first place (in my opinion).

So what I have done for past projects in cases like this, is only assign a variable, say your template has

```
<?php echo $header; ?>
other HTML stuff
```

and in the Controller you do

```
class Controller_MyController extends Controller_Template
{
    public function action_foo()
    {
        $header = View::factory('blocks/header_ss');
        $header->set('tag', 'Content');
        $this->template->set('header', $header);
    }
}
```

The upside of this is, that Kohana will automatically call `render()` when necessary and you don't need to worry about this anymore.